# What is the difference between these two approaches in the async-await pattern?

Tags: javascript, async-await

### case - A

```js
const BASE_URL = "https://bootcamp-api.codeit.kr/api";

export async function fetchData(endpoint) {
  const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/sample/${endpoint}`);
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("Fail");
  }
  return await response.json();
}

export async function getFolders() {
  return await fetchData("folder");
}

export async function getUserProfile() {
  return await fetchData("user");
}
```

### case - B

```js
const BASE_URL = "https://bootcamp-api.codeit.kr/api";

export async function fetchData(endpoint) {
  const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/sample/${endpoint}`);
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("Fail");
  }
  return await response.json();
}

export function getFolders() {
  return fetchData('folder');
}

export function getUserProfile() {
  return fetchData('user');
}
```

What's different in action?

***Edited***

Why we don't need to add 'async' and 'await' keyword in *case B*?
This cases are working the same.

Comment: Sorry is this a game of spot the difference, do you have a specific question?.

Comment: The first has `export async function` and the second `export function`; does that mean I win?

Comment: I would expect both versions of the `get*` functions to return a `Promise` which resolves to the AJAX result.  The former just makes that intent slightly more clear.  (Possibly at a miniscule performance difference.)  Do you observe something different when you test it?

Comment: Neither appear to be called however so with only the given code they can both have those removed?

Comment: Case A,  the `async` & `await` are pretty much null OP's.  @David explanation is spot on.

Answer (score 2):

An async function returns a promise. but if a promise returned from it there's no need `async` since a promise returned anyway.

For the same reason you should never do `return await` since you delay the execution of the current flow instead of returning immediately. Basically in that case you return a promise anyway but with the resolved value. The return value can be even discarded by the caller so it's even a possible performance hit if you `return await`.
Never `return await`. The case B is right but should be fixed by removing `return await`:

```
export async function fetchData(endpoint) {
  const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/sample/${endpoint}`);
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("Fail");
  }
  return response.json();
} 

export function getFolders() {
  return fetchData('folder');
}

export function getUserProfile() {
  return fetchData('user');
}
```

Comment: `return await` doesn't block, it's just pointless.  The main performance hit here, and it's very very minimal, is with that `async` keyword your creating a Promise that returns a Promise, in other words there is just one more extra Promise on the Promise chain.

Comment: @Keith, "blocking" might not be the perfect term, but it delays the execution and introduces additional unnecessary work for the event loop. And it can be definitely noticeable, especially if the usage of `await` and `async` in the rest of the code base would match what is shown in the question.

Comment: Totally agree there is a performance hit, the extra Promise on the Promise chain is not free.   And agree with `return await` should never be required, but `return (await something).something` would be fine,  The simple rule I suppose is if the return value of `await` is used within the function, it makes sense, if it's just returned makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases the code you show in both are pretty much going to work the same.  But there is one caveat, marking a function `async` will guarantee the function is a `Promise`, in your code this is not likely to be an issue, unless you spelled `fetchData` incorrectly and the caller was using `then` / `catch` etc.

eg.

```js
async function test1() {
  return fetchDataOops();
}

function test2() {
  return fetchDataOops();
}

function handleError(name) {
  return e => {
    console.log(`Handled error for ${name} and it was ${e.toString()}`);
  }
}

test1().catch(handleError('test1'));
test2().catch(handleError('test2'));
```

Notice in `test2` how the error was not handled.  This difference if using purely `async/await` would not matter, as the `try / catch` logic would handle both cases.

So in some respects `case A` you could argue gives you that little bit of extra code security, especially if the function has a mix of `async` and `sync`, and your also using `.then, .catch` handlers..

There is a small performance hit for doing this, when I say small I mean small, (but in tight loops could certainly add up) basically in your examples there is an extra Promise created, that returns a Promise.  You could also say `case - A` as mentioned in comments also gives a little bit more detail on intent, IOW: In Case B, there is no indication this function returns a Promise unless you read the code an know `fetchData` is also a `Promise`, but in `Case A` it does.

Answer (score -2):

In the first case (getFolders or getUserProfile ), the await keyword ensures that the function waits for the fetchData promise to be resolved before proceeding.

in second case the function returns the unresolved promise immediately. If you want to work with the result of the fetchData operation, you need to use await or handle the promise using .then() in the calling code.

Using await allows you to work with the result of the asynchronous operation in a more synchronous style, making the code easier to read and understand.

Comment: "the await keyword ensures that the function waits for the fetchData promise to be resolved before proceeding" this is not true, it depends on how the surrounding function is called.

Comment: @JSONDerulo Thanks for your comment, would you please explain the situation (`how the function is called`)

Comment: @ByeonginYoon "wait" implies blocking the thread. `await` doesn't *block* execution, it *yields*, so other functions can be run until the completion of the awaited promise triggers it to continue